# notation for sample space of combinations (not permutations)

Tags: probability

I know that to express the sample space of permutations of, say, tossing three dice, the set would contain all possible ordered triples of the numbers 1 through 6

i.e. the Cartesian Product {1,2,3,4,5,6} X {1,2,3,4,5,6} X {1,2,3,4,5,6}

But what if I don't care about the order the numbers appear in, i.e I want the sample space to list all possible combinations of the three dice rolls, but don't want say (1,2,2) and (2,1,2) to both appear?

is there a concise mathematical way to express this sample space? have I misunderstood something?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset

Comment: The sample space has 6x5x4=120 elements.  I don't know how to write it.